# Относительный путь в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть проблема при отображении UserCotrol'a в дизайнере, в конструкторе UserControl'a есть следующий код

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"AutoScenario");
LstScenario.Items.Clear();
foreach (FileInfo subDir in dir.GetFiles())
  {
   LstScenario.Items.Add(subDir.Name);
  }
```

программа работает без проблем но не отображает UserControl в дизайнере при этом пишет ошибку ссылаясь на неправильный путь

```
ошибка:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\AutoScenario'.
```

Comment: А вы и не должны обращаться к файловой системе в вашем UI, иначе будет, понятно, подвисать и глючить. Список файлов должен приходить из VM.

Comment: Вопрос о том почему во время выполнения программы и для представления в дизайнере разные пути?

Comment: А почему должны быть одинаковые? Откуда дизайнер знает, какой будет рабочий каталог вашей программы? Вы ведь знаете, что рабочий каталог и каталог, в котором лежит программа — это несвязанные вещи?

Comment: Согласен дизайнер не знает какой будет рабочий каталог, поэтому он по дефолту ссылает на "C:\Windows\system32\"? а после запуска получает рабочий каталог поэтому понимает и относительный путь? как же тогда указать путь относительно exe файла

Comment: Ну, вот тут целое обсуждение этой проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041505/276994

Comment: На самом деле не один из предложенных вариантов не решает данной проблемы за ее решает простая проверка на существование каталога             var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"AutoScenario");
            LstScenario.Items.Clear();
            if (Directory.Exists(dir.Name))
                foreach (FileInfo subDir in dir.GetFiles())
                    LstScenario.Items.Add(subDir.Name); и в дизайнере все снова отображается, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь выполнить разные ветви кода в зависимости о того где исполняется код - в дизайнере или в рантайме.

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
  // В дизайнере
}
else
{
  // В рантайме
}
```

Ты можешь задать рабочий каталог для отладки в свойствах проекта. Или в рантайме, используя метод [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Но тебе верно советуют - синхронные операции с файловой системой рано или поздно подвесят UI, что породит много негатива со стороны пользователей.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос но что означает "синхронные операции с файловой системой", если Вас затруднит ответить, скажите в каком направлении почитать об этом?

Comment: @XmaksasX в данном случае имеется ввиду синхронный вызов с ожиданием завершения операции. Допустим рабочий каталог расположен на сетевой шаре. Ты отправляешь запрос по SMB-протоколу, а удалённая машина по какой-то причине не отвечает или отвечает с задержкой. В результате UI подвисает на 15 секунд, а система предлагает аварийно завершить не отвечающее приложение. Юзер гадает - происходит сейчас какая-то работа или нет. А почитать можешь про await/async в реалиях WPF и async binding.

Comment: Большое спасибо пошел изучать.